# Angular Dart component scroll event

Tags: angular, dart

I want to make a button "back to top" appear once the user scrolls the page by 500px. In the AppComponent I am trying to catch the scroll event in the main Div.

```
<div class="container" scrollable>
    <router-outlet [routes]="Routes.all" ></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Neither (scroll) event inside Div nor Directive seems to work.

```
 @Directive(selector: '[scrollable]')
  class ScrollableDiv {
    final Element e;
    ScrollableDiv(this.e);
    void scrollUpdate(){
      window.onScroll.listen((event) { print('Scrolling');});
    }

    @HostListener('scroll')
    void scrolling(){
     scrollUpdate();
    }
  }
```

But if I add 'click' to @HostListener instead of 'scroll' then after a click on a page I can catch scrolling event. How can i start listening to scroll without a click and how to get the Y offset value from "event"?

Comment: It is not clear to me what do you want to do. Do you want to trigger changes on the position of the scroll bar or do you want to trigger when the user rolls the mouse wheel? 
The latter needs the "wheel" event.

Answer (score 0):

I found out two ways of doing this.

1. Add 'mouseover' instead of 'scroll' to the @HostListener. I guess it will work in 99% of cases as user always hover the page before scrolling.

> ```
> @Directive(selector: '[scrollable]')
> class ScrollableDiv {
>   final Element e;
>   ScrollableDiv(this.e);
>   void scrollUpdate(){
>     window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) {
>       var last_known_scroll_position=window.scrollY; 
>       print(last_known_scroll_position);
>     } );      
>   }
>
>   @HostListener('mouseover')
>   void scrolling(){
>     scrollUpdate();
>   }
> }
> ```

2. Use ngOnInint. It may cause memory leak if you do no add ngOnDestroy, but i use my listener in main AppComponent, so I do not need it to be destroyed before page is actually closed.

> ```
> @override
> void ngOnInit() {
>  window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) {
>   var last_known_scroll_position=window.scrollY; 
>   print(last_known_scroll_position);
>  });  
> }
> ```

So I used the second one without destroying the listener.

Comment: why do you need a mouseover? the scroll event should be enough

Comment: Consider that directives are mad to be reusable. If tomorrow you will need to use it elsewhere maybe the ngOnDestroy will be needed. I suggest you to add it anyway.
BTW I'd prefer the @HostListener syntax.. It should be enough.

Comment: If the problem is getting the scroll/wheel event add the following to "@HostListener":
@HostListener('scroll', ['\$event'])
onHostScroll(event) { .... }